# Android studio View Pull Request feature is disabled

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

All the actions related to Pull Requests are disabled in Android studio Android Studio 4.1 Canary 9.
How can I enable them?

[image: PR options disabled]
[image: Other options are enabled but PR options]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aah, make sure you are signed in to Github in android studio?

> Preferences > VersionControl > Github